# With ParseGlob how to render more than two templates in golang?

Tags: google-app-engine, parsing, go, go-templates

Tired this https://github.com/golang-samples/template/blob/master/parseglob/main.go but server is shutting down forcefully.
1)main.go
    package main

```
import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

func main() {
    t := template.New("main.tmpl")
    t = template.Must(t.ParseGlob("templates/*.tmpl"))
    err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("template execution: %s", err)
    }
}
```

2) main.tmpl

```
{{template "header"}}
<p>main content</p>
{{template "footer"}}
```

3) header.html

```
{{define "header"}}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
{{end}}
```

4) footor.html

```
{{define "footer"}}
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

Any other useful link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on my below code,

i created a howto here:
http://javatogo.blogspot.com/2013/06/howto-render-multiple-templates-with-go.html

here is an example how to render multiple templates:

```
const rootPageTemplateHtml = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{.PageTitle}}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{template "pageMenu" .}}
    {{template "pageContent" .}}
    {{template "pageFooter" .}}
  </body>
</html>
`
const pageMenuTemplateHtml = `
<div>
menu: {{.PageName}}
</div>
`

type PageContent struct {
  PageName    string
  PageContent interface{}
  PageTitle   string
}


func initTemplate(tmpl *template.Template) {
  *tmpl = *template.Must(template.New("rootPage").Parse(rootPageTemplateHtml))
  tmpl.New("pageHeader").Parse(``)
  tmpl.New("pageMenu").Parse(pageMenuTemplateHtml)
  tmpl.New("pageFooter").Parse(``)
}

func execTemplate(tmpl *template.Template, w *http.ResponseWriter, pc *PageContent) {
  if err := tmpl.Execute(*w, *pc); err != nil {
    http.Error(*w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
  }
}
```

now lets add the first page:

```
const welcomeTemplateHTML = `
<div>welcome page</div>
`

var welcomePage *template.Template

func initWelcomePageTemplate() {
  if nil == welcomePage {
    welcomePage = new(template.Template)
    initTemplate(welcomePage)
    welcomePage.New("pageContent").Parse(welcomeTemplateHTML)
  }
}

func renderWelcomePage(w *http.ResponseWriter, pc *PageContent) {
  initWelcomePageTemplate()
  execTemplate(welcomePage, w, pc)
}
```

and a second page:

```
const linksTemplateHTML = `
<div>second page</div>
`

var secondPage *template.Template

func initSecondPageTemplate() {
  if nil == secondPage {
    secondPage = new(template.Template)
    initTemplate(secondPage)
    secondPage.New("pageContent").Parse(secondTemplateHTML)
  }
}

func renderSecondPage(w *http.ResponseWriter, pc *PageContent) {
  initSecondPageTemplate()
  execTemplate(secondPage, w, pc)
}
```

to execute this different templates just add to your handler:

```
func init() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", welcome)
  http.HandleFunc("/second", second)
}

func welcome(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    pc := PageContent{"/", nil, "Welcome Page Title"}
    renderWelcomePage(&w, &pc)
}

func second(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    pc := PageContent{"/second", nil, "Second Page Title"}
    renderSecondPage(&w, &pc)
}
```

now you can add as many files as you want

Comment: @ fmt.Println.MKO : yes I tried this example before also ... but if I  render following then it is rendering with html tags. Which I dont want.                                                                               Eg:                                                                         {{define "body"}}
<body>
<p>hi</p>
</body>
{{end}}

Comment: waht do you mean with its rendering with html ? what is your input, whats your output and what do you expect ?/ want to have ?

Comment: package main

import (  
 "html/template"   
     "net/http"
    )

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { 
    s1, _ := template.ParseFiles("templates/t1.html", "templates/t2.html", "templates/t3.html") 
 s1.ExecuteTemplate(w, "t_cd", nil) 
s1.ExecuteTemplate(w, "body", nil)
   
}

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
 
}
 OutPut:                                                                      c d 
<body><p>hi</p></body>                                                                                 "In output html tags are coming which i dont want to display".

Comment: ah so your 3 templates are a main a footer and a body ? and you want that body is rendered into main ? in that case you need todo something like this:

`tmpl=template.Must(template.New("main").ParseFiles("main.html"))
tmpl.New("header").ParseFiles("header.html")
tmpl.New("body").ParseFiles("body.html")`
where main.html have at the points you want the header and body this:
`{{template "header" .}}
{{template "body" .}}`
header.html and body.html, dont need template or define statement, just plain html there, or some dynamic stuff that should be rendered inside the html

Comment: if your app is appengine app, you cant use template files, instead, just put your html inside a string in your code, and use the Parse instead of ParseFiles method

Comment: yes it is go-appengine application and parsing the files html files from templates folder... in that case base.html and other.html file is working fine. Problem in other than base.html and other.html files rendering. Whatever till now is done is Fine as per above discussion. In many docs they just explained with two html files only. But can you give link or example to explain whatever you written above?

Comment: @fmt.Fprint : Thanks, I tried the above in different way. Will add my answer soon.

Comment: i added a link for a complete howto, i have written based on the code in my answer